# import exceptions

Tags: haskell

This is my "searching in list of tuples program":

```
   import Data.List
   import Data.Char
   data BookInfo = Book Int String [String]
      deriving(Show)

   enter :: Int->String->[String]->BookInfo
   enter id name subject=Book id name subject
   bookId   (Book id _     _  ) = id
   index :: BookInfo -> Int
   index (Book id name subject) =  bookId  (Book id name subject) 
        arrayentering book bookList
         | empty book = bookList
         | otherwise  = book : bookList
         where
         empty (Book _ name subject) = all isSpace name && all (all isSpace) subject
         bubbleSort::(Ord t) => [t]->[t]
         bubbleSort[x,y,z,xs]=
                if x<y then x : [y,z,xs]
                       else y : [x,z,xs]
         superBubble::(Ord t) =>[[t]]->[[t]]
         superBubble a=map bubbleSort a
         combining::[BookInfo]->[[Int]]
         combining books=superBubble [(map index books)] 

          bsearch :: [[a]]-> a -> a -> Int 
          bsearch ms key s  

                  | elemtIndex m ms = s  return 9999
                  |
                    key=m  elemIndex m ms
                  |
                    key<m  bsearch (splitAt ms o) key o 
                   | otherwise bsearch (splitAt ms (o+2) ) key n  
                  o<-s/2-1
                  n<-length ms
         finalBsearch::(Ord)=> [a]->a->a->Int
         finalBsearch ms key s= bsearch  (combining ms) key s
```

Trying to compile it causes an error: 
`ERROR line 2 - Syntax error in input (unexpected keyword "import")`.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you indent the second line like this?

```
import Data.List
 import Data.Char
```

If so, the parser will think there is 1 statement not 2.